# Compressing short English strings in Python?

Tags: python, compression

I would like to fit 80M strings of length < 20 characters in memory and use as little memory as possible.

I would like a compression library that I can drive from Python, that will allow me to compress short (<20 char) English strings. I have about 80M of them, and I would like them to fit in as little memory as possible.

I would like maximum lossless compression. CPU time is not the bottleneck.

I don't want the dictionary stored with each string, because that would be high overhead.

I want to compress to <20% the original size. This is plausible, given that the upper bound of the entropy of English is 1.75 bits (Brown et al, 1992, http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/J/J92/J92-1002.pdf) = 22% compression (1.75/8).

Edit:

I can't use zlib because the header is too large. (If I have a string that starts at 20 bytes, there can be NO header for there to be good compression. zlib header = 200 bytes according to Roland Illing. I haven't doublechecked, but I know it's bigger than 20.)

Huffman coding sounds nice, except it is based upon individual tokens, and can't do ngrams (multiple characters).

smaz has a crappy dictionary, and compresses to only 50%.

I strongly prefer to use existing code, rather than implement a compression algorithm.

Comment: Why is the "zlib header too large"? It's less than 200 bytes.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the header is too large"?

Comment: Yes, but storing 200 bytes in a string that starts at 20 bytes will not compress things.

Comment: I see that you are downvoting everyone who is trying to help you. That will not encourage people to help you.

Comment: Sjoerd: If the answer is wrong, should I just leave it be?

Comment: You seem to want to compress each individual entry, while we commenters assume you'd compress the entire dictionary, making the header negligible. It is not clear from your question why you need to compress individual strings, do you need random access?

Comment: @JosephTurian There's a difference between "wrong" and "thanks, but that does not meet my needs". Of course, you're free vote as you see fit. I'm simply agreeing with Sjoerd that downvoting those that try to help may discourage further assistance.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't want the dictionary stored with each string, because that would be high overhead.

So build a single string with all of the desired contents, and compress it all at once with whichever solution. This solves the "header is too large" problem as well.

You can do this in a variety of ways. Probably the simplest is to create the `repr()` of a list of the strings; or you can use the `pickle`, `shelve` or `json` modules to create some other sort of serialized form.

Answer (score 1):

Make a dictionary of all words. Then, convert all words to numbers corresponding to the offset in the dictionary. If needed, you can use the first bit to indicate that the word is capitalized.

Comment: The strings are most already words. And even if this worked, I'd need to store the dictionary of words in memory.

Comment: a dictionary is unordered. What do you mean with offset?

Comment: Why is storing the dictionary of words in memory a problem? Can you explain your problem some more? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I would like to fit 80M strings of length < 20 characters in as little memory as possible. I have updated my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [zipfile](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html) from the standard library?

Answer (score 1):

There are no more than 128 different characters in English strings. Hence you can describe each character with a 7bits code. See [Compressing UTF-8(or other 8-bit encoding) to 7 or fewer bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837686/compressing-utf-8or-other-8-bit-encoding-to-7-or-fewer-bits)

Comment: This will offer 7/8s compression. I want to compress to 20% the original size. The upper bound of the entropy of English is 1.75 bits (Brown et al, 1992) = 22% compression (1.75/8).

Answer (score 1):

First, if you compress each 20-bytes string individually, your compression ratio will be miserable. You need to compress a lot of strings together to really witness some tangible benefits.

Second, 80M strings is a lot, and if you have to decompress them all to extract a single one of them, you'll be displeased by performance. Chunk your input into smaller but still large enough blocks. A typical value would be 64KB, translating into 3200 strings.

Then, you can compress each 64KB block independantly. When you need to access a single string into the block, you need to decode the entire block.

So here, there is a trade-off to decide between compression ratio (which prefer larger blocks) and random access speed (which prefer smaller blocks). You'll be the judge to select the best one.

Quick note : random access on in-memory structure usually favor fast compression algorithm, rather than strong ones. If you compress only once, but random access a lot of times, prefer some highly assymetric algorithms, such as LZ4-HC :
http://code.google.com/p/lz4hc/

According to benchmark, compression speed is only 15MB/s, but decoding speed is about 1GB/s. That translates into 16K blocks of 64KB decoded per second...